# how to coerce a vector into a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

What is the 'right' way to coerce a vector into a tibble?  I'm trying to use the tidyverse, and there seems to be a hole in it.

Say I have a vector that I want to turn into a tibble with one row (cf. one column).  According to [the documentation](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/as_tibble.html) for `tibble` I should be able to use `as_tibble_row()` (cf. `as_tibble_col()` or `as_tibble_column()` *).  However, when I try to call these functions, it seems they do not exist.  I have installed and imported `tidyverse`v3.0.1 (which contains `tibble` v2.1.3).

```
> as_tibble_row(c(a = 1, b = 2))
Error in as_tibble_row(c(a = 1, b = 2)) : 
  could not find function "as_tibble_row"
> as_tibble_col(c(a = 1, b = 2))
Error in as_tibble_col(c(a = 1, b = 2)) : 
  could not find function "as_tibble_col"
> as_tibble_column(c(a = 1, b = 2))
Error in as_tibble_column(c(a = 1, b = 2)) : 
  could not find function "as_tibble_column"
```

likewise `??as_tibble_row`, `??as_tibble_col`, `??as_tibble_column` find no results.

When I try just the simple `as_tibble()`, it gives me a tibble column, but I get a warning

```
> as_tibble(c(a = 1, b = 2))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
Warning message:
Calling `as_tibble()` on a vector is discouraged, 
because the behavior is likely to change in the future. 
Use `tibble::enframe(name = NULL)` instead.
```

Using `enframe()` as suggested gives the expected result for a column:

```
> tibble::enframe(c(a = 1, b = 2))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 b         2
```

But I still don't know how to coerce the vector into a single row.  What am I missing (perhaps the documentation needs to be updated, because it seems to reference these functions which don't seem to exist)?

---

*the described function for the column version in the documentation refers to it as `as_tibble_column()` in the description but as `as_tibble_col()` elsewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you're pointing to refers to version 3.0.1 of the package (you say you're using 2.1.3):

[image]

```
> as_tibble_col(c(a = 1, b = 2))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
> as_tibble_row(c(a = 1, b = 2))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
```

The [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/news/news.html) says that these functions were added in version 3.0.0.

Comment: Ah. Clear. there's me dyslexically thinking 2.1.3 comes after 3.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
as_tibble(t(c(a = 1, b = 2)))
```

is what you are looking for (though you don't actually specify the exact desired output here).

```
> as_tibble(t(c(a = 1, b = 2)))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
```